# gdb print won't print out something readable from my char array

Tags: c, gdb, printing

i have a `char buffer[100]` and i'm trying to use gdb to read the contents out of it at various stages of runtime.

i use `p buffer` and i get

```
"/*\000\000\000\000\000\000????X?o\000\025\202\004\b", '\0' <repeats 12 times>, ".N=?", '\0' <repeats 24 times>, "`\203\004\b\000\000\000\000L\227\004\bX????\202\004\b?\017\204\000\f?\203\000\210???i\205\004\b??r"
```

how do i get `p` to convert it into a readable format???

Comment: Make sure there is printable (readable) data in the buffer?  GDB prints what is present - not what you would like to be there.  At the moment, `strcmp(buffer, "/*") == 0`.

Comment: hmm, so i'm definitely new at this, and as a side comment, why is strcmp(buffer, "/*") == 0 important? obviously, there is way more in this buffer than just "/*" so it seems obvious to me that strcmp would return 0...

Comment: It's the "\000" that's representing the "null" which marks the end of the C string.  So your buffer, viewed as holding a C string, really contains the string "/*" (that's what Jonathan Leffler is getting at with his `strcmp` equation - note that `strcmp` returns 0 when the strings are the same).

Comment: oh, right. for some reason i assumed it would return 1. nevermind.... thank to you both!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`x/s buffer` should display the contents of the array as a null terminated string (which is what I assume you'd like).

Comment: Yeah, that's better than my way - less typing :)

Answer (score 10):

If you want to get rid of the junk after the terminating null (so you'll just see `"/*"` for this string) you can use:

```
p (char*)buffer
```

At the moment `gdb` is printing your variable as an array, so it's showing all 100 characters; casting it to `char*` makes it print it as a C string.